# MFC Custom Keyboard DLL Accessed from Application Dialog Box

Tags: dll, mfc, keyboard

The overall goal is to be able to access a pop-up keyboard through an application that I am making in MFC.

I have created a dialog box with an empty text field. I would like to be able to click the empty field and have an onscreen keyboard to enter in the data field.

Is there list of functions or tutorials that anyone can provide me with to be able to perform this function? Ultimate I will be making the keyboard from scratch, so any guidance would be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first thoughts (I might be wrong someone might correct me if i am wrong.)

1)Create your Keyboard Ui in an MFC DLL and export the KeyBoard Functions like `LaunchKB(Int screenx,int screeny)` and `CloseKB()`
functions.

2)I would subClass CEdit and CRichedit such that when the edit control gains or loses focus it would call  LaunchKB() function with windows ScreenX coordinates where the keyboard has to be displayed or CloseKB().

3) A callback function registered to dll ,which would get called for every click on the keyboard with characters clicked and these characters are to be displayed in the edit control.

This is just my thought ,there may be better ways to implement as well.